# ESPAsyncWebserver blocking Azure IoTHub MQTT connection

Tags: azure-iot-hub, arduino-esp8266

I'm trying to set up a connection to IoTHub on my ESP8266 device. The example works just fine on its own. My problem begins when I try to include an AsyncWebserver to host an HTML page. Just declaring the server variable seems to break IoTHub's ability to make socket connections. I believe to replicate my problem you can simply import ESPAsyncWebserver and declare an AsyncWebserver in the sample IoTHub connection provided in this link.

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/iot-hub-feather-huzzah-client-app/tree/master/app

My Serial output looks like this:

```
Sending message: {"deviceId":"Esp-home","messageId":31,"temperature":29,"humidity":36}.
IoTHubClient accepted the message for delivery.
dowork TLSIO_STATE_OPENING_WAITING_DNS
dowork TLSIO_STATE_OPENING_WAITING_SOCKET
dowork TLSIO_STATE_OPENING_WAITING_SSL
Error opening socket 0
Calling error callback
Error: failure opening connection to endpoint
tlsio_arduino_destroy called while not in TLSIO_STATE_CLOSED.
```

I'm using platformIO, and have copied all the functions to one single C++ file, but other than that I changed nothing. I would appreciate the slightest light anyone can shed on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same error. I tracked it down to an out-of-memory fault in the ESP8266WiFi library. The function WiFiClientSecure::_connectSSL tried to allocate a 16K input buffer when there was only 12K available on the heap. I sure wish people who develop stuff could return something more comprehensive than just 'false' or 0. Anyway, the ESP8266 seems to be too limited memory-wise so I am moving to ESP32. I guess 8266 is ok as long as you don't need to use SSL.